Outbound Call to a Teams End Point using AppHostedMedia in Bot Framework: How to generate Media Session Configuration?
Re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-peer-to-peer-voip-call-with-application-hosted-media
We want a bot that can make an outbound call to another Teams End Point and pipe in application hosted media.  The issue is that all Microsoft examples gloss over how to provide the Media Session Configuration blob in the graph call.

 "blob": "<Media Session Configuration>"


We suspect that should contain an SDP offer, to let the remote know how to connect to the media stream,  but can not find another class in the Graph Communications SDK or Bot Framework that can manage it.   (There are some classes here but no sample code to clarify)  https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/calls/index.html
Failing which, what is information is expected in that blob and how can it be generated automatically for each call assuming the host IP and port ranges and protocols (UDP/TCP), supported media types (PCM etc) are known.
(On the same Microsoft page and linked pages, there are number of unanswered queries about the same topic)
For Inbound calls to the bot using App Hosted Media, this handshake is done by the SDK itself.

Here is the sample code to show how to create local media session:
microsoft-graph-comms-samples/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot/FrontEnd/Bot/Bot.cs at master · microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples (github.com)

HI @Sayali-MSFT.   Can you please elaborate in which class on the referenced file it is using the local media session to create an outbound call?  Seems that it is setting up the session for handing inbound calls.

please have look into this document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/call-automation/quickstart-make-an-outbound-call?tabs=visual-studio-code&pivots=programming-language-csharp
Hope it is helpful!!

That is for ACS and not bot framework
